# Why does my div not center properly?

Tags: jquery, css, blockui

I'm using $.blockUI with jQuery to show a modal dialogue. The HTML looks like:

```
<div id="progressDialogue" class="mp_modalpopup">
    <div class="mp_container">
        <div class="mp_header">
            <span id="pd_header_text" class="mp_msg">Please wait..</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mp_body">
            <img src="ajax-loader.gif" style="text-align:center" alt="loading" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like:

```
.mp_modalpopup
{
    font-family: arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    z-index:999;    
}

.mp_container
{
    width: 400px;
    border: solid 1px #808080;
    border-width: 1px 1px;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}

/* removed mp_header, mp_body, mp_msg CSS for brevity */
```

This will happily render smack bang in the center of the page on top of other HTML.

However if I set `display:none` in the `.mp_modalpopup` CSS class and then use $.blockUI to make it visible, in IE 8 the dialogue centers itself vertically but aligns left with half of the dialogue off the page and in Google Chrome and Firefox the dialogue is not visible at all (but blockUI is working because the page greys out).

This is the blockUI javascript:

```
$.blockUI.defaults.css = {};

$.blockUI({ 
    message: $('#progressDialogue'), 
    overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#000', opacity: 0.1 },
    css: {backgroundColor: '#00f', color: '#100'} 
});
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because blockUI is also trying to center your `<div>`.  If you remove all positioning from your CSS, it should work.

Remove this:

```
bottom: 50%;
right: 50%;
position: absolute;
```

And this

```
left: 50%;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
```

Alternatively, you could disable the `blockUI` centering like this:

```
$.blockUI({ 
    centerX: false, 
    centerY: false, 
    message: $('#progressDialogue'), 
    overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#000', opacity: 0.1 },
    css: {backgroundColor: '#00f', color: '#100'} 
});
```

Comment: @Kev - What happens when removing your CSS and letting it center?

Comment: there's a bunch of legacy HTML and CSS that surrounds my own code (classic ASP includes etc). The problem is further up the tree as it were and a bit of a major rewrite is needed to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I just found a very easy solution.

If you block an element instead of the entire page, blockUI gives you the options to use centerX and centerY.

I blocked the element html and that was it.  My div was horizontally and vertically centered.  Ofourse I didn't want it vertically centered, so I set centerY to false, and in the CSS set it to top: '5%', as below.  Also make sure you set the width of the element in the blockUI css.

```
$('html').block({ message: $('#layOver'),
    centerX: true,
    centerY: false,
    css: {
            top: '5%',
            width: '720px',
            height: 'auto',
            cursor: 'null',
            border: 'none',
            textalign: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'auto', 
    }, 
    overlayCSS:  { 
            opacity: 0.4 ,
            cursor: 'null',
    } 
});
```